# Selenium C#: Assert verifying if text field is uneditable

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to write a script to assert if the text field in question isn't editable. I was attempting to write a verification hidden = "true", because that is what ultimately is hiding the editable text box. How would I be able to verify something like this? and is this the way I should be handling such a verification? Thanks for your responses in advance.

Here is the html

```html
<div id="ctl00_contentMain_sponsorInfo">
<fieldset>
    <legend>
        Referral Information
    </legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            The name of your referrer is Name…
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="ctl00_contentMain_sponsorUsername" class="textBig" type="text" hidden="true" style="width:270px;" req="false" max="30" value="Name" name="ctl00$contentMain$sponsorUsername"></input>
        </li>
    </ol>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned the best way to test this scenario is to see if the `hidden` `attribute` has a value `true`

```
IWebElement element = Driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$contentMain$sponsorUsername"));
if (element.GetAttribute("hidden").Contains("true"))
{
    Assert.Pass("Your message");
}
```

> Note: You do have to make sure the element exist. You can use some explicit wait with something like
>
> ```
> var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
> wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("something ")));
> ```
>
> in order to grab the attribute. This case Selenium will work just fine since you are not interacting with the element.

Comment: If I change the line Contains("true") to Contains("false") it still passes. Is there a better way to verify this?

Comment: Is there another element having same name? It should not

Comment: After searching through the page, that is the only element with that name. I will try to add some wait time, maybe that is the issue.

Comment: Can you provide more `html`? I can possible give you an xpath or css for uniquely identifying the element

Comment: Above is the entire Div containing this piece, let me know if you need more.

Comment: @DEnumber50 Try `div#ctl00_contentMain_sponsorInfo li>input#ctl00_contentMain_sponsorUsername` as cssSelector

Comment: I get the same result, false or true passes the test

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver interacts only with the visible elements. You can use `JavaScriptExecutor`.

```
 IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
 string hiddenStatus = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return document.getElementById('ctl00_contentMain_sponsorUsername').hidden");
```

hiddenStatus will have true/false

Comment: I could not get this to work, stating that getElementByID isn't a valid call. On a note I am using NUnit.

Comment: @DEnumber50, it is `getElementById`. sorry..corrected

Comment: TestName: System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.String'. Is the error I receive now.